# How to test both, the error class and the error message for a rejected promise in one step?

Tags: jestjs

I changed certain promises to return not just an error message but additional info (e.g. error code). For this I switched from plain rejection messages to an own error class. Now I would like to test both: the error class in the rejection and its message. Previously I had:

```js
        await expect(core.createDatabaseFile("non-existing/test.sqlite3")).rejects
            .toBe("No permissions to access the directory.");
```

I could change that to:

```js
        await expect(core.createDatabaseFile("non-existing/test.sqlite3")).rejects
            .toBeInstanceOf(ResponseError);
        await expect(core.createDatabaseFile("non-existing/test.sqlite3")).rejects
            .toBe("No permissions to access the directory.");
```

but that would require to execute the test twice, which can become expensive. Is there a way to do the check in one step, similar to chai's `rejectedWith`?